# How limited is recur?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-call-optimization

As far as I can tell, Clojure's `recur` is backed by the compiler whereas in other lisps it is implemented at a lower level.

As I read, this wouldn't be a "general" TCO. Aside from the obvious (a keyword + checking are needed), is in any way `recur` less powerful?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to support indirect (co-recursive) TCO with `recur`; the call-stack is still done via the JVM. Similarly `call-cc` can't be done because the JVM doesn't support it and clojure doesn't implement it's own [stackless] call-stack (I think `DrSchema` did?) which would make it incompatible with Java classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would that imply at a practical level (e.g. better performance, being able to express more forms of recursion)?

Comment: "Playing nicely on the JVM" and being able to interop. with Java (and other languages). Scala has similar ... "restrictions" :-)

Comment: As far as I know, clj plays rather nice on the JVM! Feel free to expand your point as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it does. And this is *why* `recur` is done how it is: with "compiler magic". Otherwise clojure would need to live/run inside it's *own* VM/call-stack in the JVM -- which would pretty much ruin a good chunk of interoperability -- that had some form of stackless/modifiable support. The JVM just doesn't work that way.

Comment: They could have had the clj compiler look for situations where it could emit bytecode that would allow the tail call to occur w/o recur. They chose to make put it under the programmer's explicit control though since the runtime does not inherently support it.

Comment: to answer "What would that imply at a practical level" - the clojure/jvm approach means that if you several functions that call each other recursively, then you can be limited by the stack in a way that could be avoided with tco (if the calls were tail calls).  i could imagine, for example, a recursive descent parser, which typically is a bunch of small functions that call each other, being limited in this way (and i maintain one in python, where i use trampolining as a work-around).

Comment: also, while i understand what you mean, isn't tco implemented by the compiler in languages where it is supported?

Comment: finally, i wonder if lazy sequences help ameliorate this?  you might write mutually recursive code because you want to delay some expensive computation until it is actually needed (and it might not be, depending on local logic) while processing a sequence of data.  lazy sequences solve that issue in a different way.  anyway, in practice it is not a big issue, but it is an annoyance that is constantly there, making the language uglier than it should be.

Comment: As ivant says, we already have `trampoline` which would avoid stack consumption - the only drawback being some syntactic clutter. On the second issue, I honestly don't know. On lazy sequences, yes, they're a nice (and actually idiomatic) way of recursion, in which fns can call themselves 'by name' rather than with `recur`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recur` only supports tail-recursion optimization, which is a subclass of general TCO. Clojure also supports mutual or indirect recursion through `trampoline`.

**EDIT**
<strike>Also, I think general TCO was expected to land in JVM with Java 7 and `recur` was meant as a temporary solution. Then Oracle happened.</strike> I've mixed that with Project Lambda's (adding closures in Java) schedule

Comment: Would we have to bother trampolining if there was general TCO?

Comment: @vemv, no. Trampolining exist to handle another common case (but less so than direct recursion) of TCO, but TCO is more general than that. It's actually quite easy conseptually: all it says is, that if a function A is calling a function B and then all it does is return back the result of B to A's caller, it can just "jump" to B instead of "calling" B, and B will return directly to A's caller. Tail recursion is the same optimization, but only when A is calling itself.

Comment: (continued) With trampolining, you call `trampoline` and instruct it to call function A. A returns to `trampoline` with instruction to call B. B can then instruct `trampoline` to call A or something else. Thus, the indirect caller (A, B) is removed from the stack and only `trampoline` stays there. It works, but it requires cooperation from all participants, so it's not as general and as elegant as general TCO.

Comment: Any reference about "I think general TCO was expected to land in JVM with Java 7" part ? If not, it should be edited out.

Comment: @Skeptic I haven't realized this is Wikipedia ;) Anyway, I've checked and it seems that I mixed Project Lambda's schedule with that, so I'll remove this part from my answer. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

recur differs slightly from full TCO in that **`recur` works with both loops and functions** and does not do some of the things that a full implementation of TCO would. The philosophical backing for this is to **make the special part look special** as opposed to silently optimizing a uniform syntax.

Comment: this is misleading; recur is significantly less powerful than tco as explained in other answers.

Comment: I did not say it was more powerful, it does less and is more obvious about it.

Comment: hmmm.  by my reading "differs ... because" implies that *the* difference is that "recur works both...".  i guess it's just unfortunate phrasing.